# uilabel view not aligning to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

i have tried everything like

```
textLabel.textAlignment =NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

but nothing seem to work bellow is my code. inside cellforrawatindexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.messageList dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ChatListItem"];

    if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OutGoing" owner:self options:nil];
        }
        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat_b2.png"]];
            textLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(21,12, 241,30)];
    NSString * test=[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xml_msg];
    textLabel.text = test;
    textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [textLabel sizeToFit];
    [cell addSubview:textLabel];
    return cell;
}
```

here is the screenshots:[image: App ScreenShot]

here you can see(in red) text is aligned left i want it to align right please help me solving this issue.

Comment: Where do you place that label. ? And what you are using Autolayout/AutoResizing .. ?

Comment: using AutoResizing

Comment: This method is obsolete. Its high time you use autoLayout.  Please check the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/). Just give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `[textLabel sizeToFit]` label frame will be sized so text fits in it, so your label width will be same as text and align to right will leave text in place. Comment this line and it'll work.

Edit:

```
[textLabel sizeToFit];
[textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(21,12,241,textLabel.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: @VixHunk in simulator go to dropdown menu Debug and turn on "Color Blended Layers", this will give you clue where is label exactly and what is its size

Comment: yes you are right but when i comment [textLabel sizeToFit] it work per complete message goes in one single line.

Comment: @VixHunk great, I'm glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sizetoFit` then your label size will decrease according to content size. it is not issue of alignment. remove this line and then add `textLabel.textAlignment =NSTextAlignmentRight;` and check it should work i think.

Answer (score 0):

You are always setting textLabel frame to following frame :

```
textLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(21,12, 241,30)];
```

So only the label appears in left. Try changing the label frame according to send/Receive message.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score -1):

Your label is constraints to the frame that your have given

```
textLabel =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(21,12, 241,30)];
```

So it is right aligned to the frame that you have given that is your label is aligned to that particular width which is 30 ......you should give the width of the label equals to the width of the cell and then it will right aligned according to your cell.